# data getting cut off at ampersand sign

Tags: php, xml

I have a web service to place a booking. When the data comes if there is any ampersand(`&` or `&amp;`), the XML data getting cut off at that point and I am loosing whatever after that. I have even tried placing the ampersand inside CDATA but it's the same. Can anyone help me to fix this? I am using PHP 5.3

Comment: Show some XML or we can't help you.

Comment: validation of input would help or use php-pdo if you are working with database... http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what APIs you are using to read the XML, but many APIs supply text data from the parser to the application in a sequence of chunks, and expect you to assemble the chunks. It's very common when the API specification allows it for the parser to choose to break the chunks at entity boundaries (i.e. ampersands) as this reduces the amount of character moving required.

It's also very common to find applications written by people who were unaware of this and ignore all chunks after the first...

Comment: I use the simplexml_load_string() but I am not even getting the whole data to the parser. 

For an example I post/curl this xml (<test>Text1 &amp; Text2</test>) to a url(.../WS.php). On the first line of the code(WS.php) if I log/print the posted data I will get up to '<test>Text1' nothing after that. It's just getting cut off at the ampersand sign. That's the problem I am having.....